# Django form, request.post and initial

Tags: django, forms, validation, post

I have a django form where I need to set a value for validation purposes which is not passed in as part of the standard Post request.

In my code I currently have something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        postform = CreatePostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'post_type':post.post_type})

        if postform.is_valid():
                .....
```

The value post_type is a selection with a value of something like 'QUE'

The issue I am having is that this does not appear to be valid. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to add the post_type value into the CreatePostForm class before the validation takes place.

Please note I do not want to expose this value on the form so including it as part of the post is not an option.

Comment: Is 'post_type' a field on the form?  It would help if you could post at least the fields of your CreatePostForm, so we know what type of validation is being run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to make it a property on the form class that you hand in as an argument when you instantiate it:

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.Form/ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, post_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreatePostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.post_type = post_type

postform = CreatePostForm(post_type=post.post_type, request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Doesn't work for me ... did you miss a self parameter in **__init__()**?

Comment: Gah, You are correct. The first parameter in the __init__ should have been self.

Comment: Just out of interest, why wouldn't this work with pulling it out of kwargs? It doesn't seem to, but I'm curious why :)

Comment: You can. You just need to do: `post_type = kwargs.pop('post_type', None)` *before* calling `super()`