# Passing Data From View to Model Django

Tags: django

I'm working on how to passing data from View to Model.
I want to pass request.user.id from view to model through save method and put it on created_by field.

Here is my view.py codes:

```py
    def dashboardCategoryCreate(request):
        form = CategoryForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                form.save(request.user.id) # I Wanto To Pass This Value
                return redirect('dashboard-category')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'category/category_form.html', context)
```

And I try to catch this data on models.py and modify field created_by with userId value

```py
    def save(self, userId=None):
        self.created_by = userId 
        super().save()
```

There is no error but value is not passing.
How to do that? Or maybe there is another way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer solve your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994619/django-form-request-post-and-initial

Comment: That's rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `commit=False` to `form.save()`, this returns an unsaved instance, then manually set the user on this instance before saving

```
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            category = form.save(commit=False)
            category.created_by = request.user
            category.save()
            return redirect('dashboard-category')
```

Comment: Still not working, am I miss something?

Comment: @DevelopmentFlazHost did you remove the save method you added to the model?

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the save method on the model and it work fine. Thank you bro, you save my time.