# Django form add initial data to bound form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to add initial data from 1 form into the second form but I cannot seem to get it work.
I've tried different methods but the closest I got came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994619/django-form-request-post-and-initial)

Here is my code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    laptop_select_form = LaptopSelectForm(request.POST)
    if laptop_select_form.is_valid():
        laptop_model_id = literal_eval(laptop_select_form.cleaned_data['model'])[0]

        laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm(request.POST, laptop_id=laptop_model_id)

    if laptop_for_parts_form.is_valid():
else:
    laptop_select_form = LaptopSelectForm()
    laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm()
```

And the form

```
class LaptopForPartsForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, laptop_id=0, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LaptopForPartsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.laptop_id = laptop_id

class Meta:
    model = LaptopForParts
    fields = ('__all__')
    widgets={'laptop_id': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm(request.POST, laptop_id=laptop_model_id)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'laptop_id'
```

Can someone more experienced please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the request.POST data and added the laptop_id before form validation

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    laptop_select_form = LaptopSelectForm(request.POST)
    if laptop_select_form.is_valid():
        # Get laptop model ID from laptop_select_form
        laptop_model_id = literal_eval(laptop_select_form.cleaned_data['model'])[0]

        # Change immutable request.POST form data to add model ID
        _mutable = request.POST.copy()
        _mutable['laptop_id'] = laptop_model_id

        laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm(_mutable)

    if laptop_for_parts_form.is_valid():
        laptop_for_parts_form.save()
else:
    laptop_select_form = LaptopSelectForm()
    laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the error `got multiple values for argument 'laptop_id'` originated from the fact that you provided the `'laptop_id'` argument twice to the `LaptopForPartsForm`. You first provided the `'laptop_id'` argument implicitly inside the `request.POST`, and then, you provided it again explicitely by stating `laptop_id=laptop_model_id`.

You could possibly solve this by providing the `'laptop_id'` argument only once, e.g.:

```
laptop_for_parts_form = LaptopForPartsForm(laptop_id=laptop_model_id)
```